Correct & concise way to use PyO3 Bindings (similar to pybind11)
Say I have the following C++ Date class. Using pybind11 I can easily wrap it to be used in Python:
/* date.hpp */

class Date
{
public:
    int year, month, day;
    
    Date(int year, int month, int day);

    Date add_days(int N) const;  // Returns new date with N days added
    bool is_weekend() const;     // Returns true if date is Sat or Sun
};

/* date_bindings.cpp */

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <date.hpp>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(date_py, m) {
    py::class_<Date>(m, "Date")
        .def(py::init<int, int, int>(), py::arg("year"), py::arg("month"), py::arg("day"))
        .def("add_days",        &Date::add_days, py::arg("N"))
        .def("is_weekend",      &Date::is_weekend)
        .def_readwrite("year",  &Date::year)
        .def_readwrite("month", &Date::month)
        .def_readwrite("day",   &Date::day);
}

Now, I want to do the same in Rust. So I implemented my Date class and then used PyO3 to wrap it. See code below.
I've noticed that the PyO3 bindings contain a lot of boilerplate, and hence they are much longer compared to pybind11:

14 lines with pybind11
54 lines with PyO3

Am I using PyO3 correctly? Are there ways to shorten the code to achieve a similar level of "conciseness" as is the case for pybind11?
edit: If there is a way to create bindings without the DatePy helper struct, I would actually prefer that.
/* date.rs */

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Date {
    pub year: u16,
    pub month: u8,
    pub day: u8
}

impl Date {
    pub const fn add_days(&self, N: u8) -> Self {
        // Simplified logic for demonstration purposes
        Date{year: self.year, month: self.month, day: self.day + N}
    }
    pub const fn is_weekend(&self) -> bool {
        // ...
        true
    }
}

/* date_bindings.rs */

use pyo3::prelude::*;
use my_library::Date;

#[pyclass(name = "Date")]
struct DatePy {
    _date: Date
}

#[pymethods]
impl DatePy {
    #[new]
    fn new(year: u16, month: u8, day: u8) -> Self {
        DatePy { _date: Date{year, month, day} }
    }
    fn add_days(&self, N: u8) -> PyResult<Self> {
        Ok(DatePy{_date: self._date.add_days(N)})
    }
    fn is_weekend(&self) -> PyResult<bool> {
        Ok(self._date.is_weekend())
    }
    #[getter]
    fn get_year(&self) -> PyResult<u16> {
        Ok(self._date.year)
    }
    #[getter]
    fn get_month(&self) -> PyResult<u8> {
        Ok(self._date.month)
    }
    #[getter]
    fn get_day(&self) -> PyResult<u8> {
        Ok(self._date.day)
    }
    #[setter]
    fn set_year(&mut self, year: u16) -> PyResult<()> {
        self._date.year = year;
        Ok(())
    }
    #[setter]
    fn set_month(&mut self, month: u8) -> PyResult<()> {
        self._date.month = month;
        Ok(())
    }
    #[setter]
    fn set_day(&mut self, day: u8) -> PyResult<()> {
        self._date.day = day;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[pymodule]
fn date_py(m: &Bound<'_, PyModule>) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<DatePy>()?;
    Ok(())
}


Assuming you do not want to give up the DatePy -> Date wrapping, I would say "judicious use of macros to generate the getters and setters".

@Botje I only created DatePy as a helper struct. If there is a way to create bindings without it, I am not opposed to it.

You can transfer the #[pyclass] annotation to Date and put #[pyo3(get, set)] annotations on the member fields

@Botje If I add the #[pyclass] annotation to my original Date class, then that means my core rust class & Python bindings will be merged into one? Is there no way to keep them independent & simply expose the class to Python? Similar to the pybind example?

I don't know how exactly the C++ works, but your snippet doesn't seem to have a dedicated PyDate either, so why do you want one for Rust but not for C++?

@cafce25 I don't actually want to use a DatePy helper class. Going by Botje's suggestion, the alternative is to add #[pyclass] to my original Date class. But the downside of that seems to be that now my core Date rust class and PyO3 bindings are bundled into one. As opposed to keeping the core implementation & bindings nicely separated. I am probably misunderstanding the PyO3 way of things, hence my question.

The two approaches are incomparable: Pybind creates the Python class descriptor based on pointers to member functions and instance variables, whereas PyO3 relies on a metric ton of procedural macros that interpret the struct definition to generate descriptors. You could try raising an issue on the PyO3 GitHub repository but I think it will be a significant architectural change. Consider writing a macro that generates the getters and setters for you.

@Botje I remember already seeing a PyO3 issue about that, but I can't find it now.
